# How to join table many to one via supabase in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, postgresql, join, supabase, supabase-js

I have a table where when I test it with the following query `select *, category_product from product inner join category on product.category_id = category.id inner join type on product.type_product = type.id` the results are what I want, then when I look at the supabase documentation for joining tables I only see one to one join, how can I convert the query above with my code in reactjs

My code now is

```
const SelectProduct = async (orderBy, brand, type) => {
   let query = supabase
  .from('product')
  .select('*, category_product', { count: 'exact' })
  .innerJoin('category', 'product.category_id', 'category.id')
  .innerJoin('type', 'product.type_product', 'type.id');;


    if (brand && brand.length > 0) {
        query = query.in('product_brand', brand);
    }
    if (type && type.length > 0) {
        query = query.in('type_product', type);
    }
    if (orderBy && orderBy === "1") {
        query.order('price', { ascending: false })
    }
    if (orderBy && orderBy === "-1") {
        query.order('price')
    }
    if (orderBy && orderBy === "2") {
        Swal.fire({
            icon: 'info',
            title: 'Coming Soon..',
            html: '<p class="text-xl">This Feature will be available in the next version of our application.</p>',
        });
    }
    const { data, error, count } = await query;
    if (error) {
        Swal.fire({
            icon: "error",
            title: "Oops...",
            text: `${error}`
        })
        throw new Error(error.message);
    }
    console.log("Data : ", data);
    return { data, error, count };
}
```

and i got this error
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/kTzwh.png)

I hope to be able to take the data according to the query I wrote above and according to the results produced by the above query

Answer (score 0):

You can find an example in the supabase-js reference docs: https://supabase.com/docs/reference/javascript/select?example=querying-referenced-table-with-inner-join

```js
const { data, error } = await supabase
  .from('cities')
  .select('name, countries!inner(name)')
  .eq('countries.name', 'Indonesia')
```